# How to get ng-model to bind to variable in nested ng-repeat ($scope.{outerloop.name}.data[innerloop.name])

Tags: angularjs

The UI is built with 2 ng-repeats. The top level is specified by a json and has fields like patient, facility, dr. Each of these can be expanded into detail data like the patient name, address, etc, the specs of which are populated by a different api call.

General structure:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in json"><!--top level input and expand button-->
    <div class="expands">
        <input ng-repeat="subfield in details" ng-model="and this is the problem...">
```

The data is in the scope as follows:

```
$scope.idpatient.data['patients.name']
$scope.idpatient.data['patients.address']
$scope.idfacility.data['facilities.address']
and so on
```

So I'm trying to bind ng-model to {{field.name}}.data[subfield.key], and it doesn't let me parse variables from field. I've heard weird stuff happens with scope and ng-repeat, but if I put in the string literally (`idpatient.data[subfield.key]`) it binds fine to data for that object. It seems like I'm trying to do something pretty simple but I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out how.

PS: I've never used angular before and inherited a system that I believe breaks a lot of best-use rules. Please be gentle if I'm committing an angular cardinal sin

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a bunch of patient info objects in details and the values of that object should be used as indexes in another collection of objects to look up what to bind to?  Why not just pull the data out of those collections and put it right on the patient info objects?

Comment: subfields exists as a (possibly hacky) way to tell the UI what to display in what order. So the view loops through a what-to-display array (mostly contains stuff like ui-order, sql-type, is-hidden). The actual information is stored in $scope.idpatient.data, $scope.idfacility.data, etc

Answer (score 0):

Putting data in `$scope.objdata[field.name][subfield.key]` binds correctly. I knew it had to be stupid simple

(too bad the code throughout our system expects it to be in `$scope.objname.data[key]` format...)